# How to clear Orphaned FSPs using Power Shell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have lot of FSPs present on Active Directory for which membership has been removed. They still exist in container  `CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=name`. How can I write a power shell script to remove all of those which have **no** `memberOf` attribute

I tried

```
PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(&(!(memberOf=*))(memberOf=cn*))" -SearchBase "CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=name"
PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp.Count
0
```

Below is giving FSPs which have memberOf

```
PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp = Get-ADObject -Filter {memberOf -notlike "*"} -SearchBase "CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=name"
PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp.Count
41523
```

Comment: `(!(memberOf=*))` and `(memberOf=cn*)` are mutually exclusive. Change the LDAP filter to just `(!(memberOf=*))` and pipe results to `Remove-ADObject`

Comment: It is giving wrong result, These are FSPs which are orphaned. `PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp = Get-ADObject -LDAPFilter "(!(memberOf=*))" -SearchBase "CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=name"
PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp.Count
41523`

Comment: Basically it is giving all FSPs

Comment: `PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp = Get-ADObject -Filter * -SearchBase "CN=ForeignSecurityPrincipals,DC=domain,DC=name"
PS C:\Users\simpleguy> $fsp.Count
41523`